# What happens to tags from a question that was migrated to another site were the tags doesn't exist?

Tags: discussion, tags, migration

I post a question with the [x](/questions/tagged/x) tag on SO, the question get migrated to the site were the question does fit the most. The tag doesn't exist on that site were the question got migrated to. Will the tag get removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the tag does not exist on the destination site, the tag is simply dropped from the question as part of the migration process.

If this would result in the question having no tags on the destination site, then the migration will be fully rejected (not created on the other site at all) unless one of these is true:

- If it was migrated by a diamond moderator, the question gets the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag, which **must** be changed to a real tag the next time someone edits the question.
- If it is migrated to the site's Meta, it always gets the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag anyways, so the check is meaningless.
- If one of the tags dropped is an intrinsic tag, it will also get [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged). E.g. if the question was tagged as "ubuntu" and then migrated to Ask Ubuntu, obviously they don't have a plain "ubuntu" tag there.